# Gmail and Outlook injecting spaces into hyperlink URLs

Tags: python, email, url, kibana, smtplib

I have some python code that sends out emails with urls embedded inside `"<a href="link">Link</a>"` tags.

Clicking on the links from Gmail or the Outlook 365 web mail client leads to broken pages, due to the both of them appearing to insert either a raw space character or a '%20' in the URL. Interestingly, it appears to happen at the same location with both clients.

The link is a Kibana dashboard link so there is embedded [Rison](https://github.com/Nanonid/rison) code.

The link should be the following:

```
<a href="http://localhost:5601/app/kibana?#/visualize/edit/BetterPie?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,value:0),time:(from:now-60d,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:'animals',key:breed,negate:!f,value:'lion'),query:(match:(breed:(query:lion,type:phrase)))),('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:'animals',key:age,negate:!f,value:'2'),query:(match:(age:(query:2,type:phrase)))),('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:'animals',key:name,negate:!f,value:'nala'),query:(match:(name:(query:nala,type:phrase))))),linked:!f,query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),uiState:(spy:(mode:(fill:!f,name:!n))),vis:(aggs:!((id:'1',params:(),schema:metric,type:count),(id:'2',params:(field:breed,order:desc,orderBy:'1',size:5),schema:segment,type:terms),(id:'3',params:(field:age,order:desc,orderBy:'1',size:5),schema:segment,type:terms),(id:'4',params:(field:name,order:desc,orderBy:'1',size:5),schema:segment,type:terms)),listeners:(),params:(addLegend:!t,addTooltip:!t,isDonut:!f,shareYAxis:!t),title:'BetterPie',type:pie))">Dashboard Link</a>
```

But it either a '%20' or a space gets injected here:

```
query:'*')),%20uiState
```

I'm using python's [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) module to encode the message and send the email, by doing the following:

```
htmlEnc = MIMEText(body, 'html')
```

Not sure why the space gets injected, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to consider intermediary URL shortener/redirect as a way to conceal the true URL from webmail clients? Email service providers are doing this by default on all email links for tracking purposes.

Comment: @revelt That's an option, but I'm not sure if that would 100% solve the issue. It's possible that the client is inserting spaces due to the length of the email body, so even if the url link were shorter, spaces may still appear, since there is other information in the html that's being added.

Comment: I can't confirm 100% but if I remember right, URL's in email have 256 chars limit. It might be even less. But since your URL's are not chopped off, that's a different case. Regarding spaces in email, it's Word rendering engine adding spaces where imaginary paper would end, but again, it's a different too as you get %20 added, which is different..

Comment: @revelt Right, and it looks like the spaces in that Word rendering engine aren't " " characters, but rather page breaks and formatting issues

Comment: Do you use the `email` Python standard module to format your email? Please specify this in your question since the solution will depend on how you format and encode your email. The `smtplib` standard module does not do any email encoding, it just takes care of the SMTP communication.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in PHP in regards to sending email. The issue for me was the 1,000 characters per line issue which automatically causes a line break to be inserted at the 1,000th character ... which might just be your URL. To fix the issue in PHP sent email, first I added **Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable** to the email header. Second, I processed the body of my email through the PHP function *quoted_printable_encode()*. I don't know the Python equivalent function, but hopefully my solution to the same type of issue helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that email lines MUST be at most 998 characters. If you send an email with a longer line to a Postfix server, Postfix will insert line breaks into the message before forwarding the message on to its final destination. Line breaks are treated as spaces in the HTML email.

You shouldn't send email with lines longer than 998 characters; in fact the standard [recommends](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1) at most 78 characters per line. A way to send HTML with lines longer than 998 characters is to use a so-called `Content-Transfer-Encoding` such as quoted-printable or base64. Luckily, if you're using the `email` Python standard module, this can be achieved as follows.

You should call the [`Message.set_charset()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.set_charset) method with a [`Charset`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.charset.html#email.charset.Charset) instance that specifies a Content-Transfer-Encoding of quoted-printable.

```
from email.charset import Charset, QP
import email.message
def fix_content_transfer_encoding(message: email.message.Message):
    charset = Charset('utf-8')
    charset.body_encoding = QP
    message.set_charset(charset)
```

The Django project uses quoted-printable by default from Django 1.10 onwards; see [Django #22561 (EmailMessage should respect RFC2822 on max line length)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22561).

---

On the topic of line length limits in email: Not all mail servers obey the 998-character limit as strictly as the Postfix software. In fact, the Yahoo webmail client will happily send invalid emails with References:-headers longer than 998 characters. Since Yahoo's strict DMARC policy requires that References: headers are not changed by intermediate mail servers, this causes legitimate Yahoo mail to be rejected by DMARC if it is forwarded through an oblivious Postfix server.